# App that would open a url based on the current date in a browser

Tags: applications, browser, 7.0-nougat, automation

I am looking for an app or a way how to automate opening a URL based on current date on the Android 7.0 phone:

On 2017-07-01 it would open the following url in a browser:

```
http://myserver.com/daily_reports/Day_20170701.htm
```

eventually

```
http://myserver.com/weekly_reports/Week_2017_27.htm
```

Since the ISO number of the current week is 27.

Is there any solution for that out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) this is very easy.

Setup a task like this:

1. Code → Run Shell:

   - Command: `date +"%Y%m%d"`
   - Store Output In: `%date`
2. App → Launch App → select your browser app:

   - Data: static URL part appended with `%date` as required. E.g.

     ```
     http://myserver.com/daily_reports/Day_%date.htm
     ```

For weekly URL, create an another task:

1. Code → Run Shell:

   - Command: `date +"%Y_%V"`
   - Store Output In: `%week_no`
2. App → Launch App → select your browser app:

   - Data: static URL part appended with `%week` as required. E.g.

     ```
     http://myserver.com/Weekly_reports/Week_%week_no.htm
     ```

You can save these two tasks, create a shortcut to them on your home screen and tap that shortcut to open the concerned URL. Or, you can setup a profile in Tasker for your requisite automation and attach those tasks to that.

Comment: Great, tasker is really cool for this.