# How to get tomorrow's date and next week's number for use in Tasker

Tags: tasker, shell, command-line, date-and-time

Based on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182991/103777) I am looking for a way how to get tommorow's date and next week number to use in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) app, **Run Shell Command**.

I have tried:

`date -d '+1 day' +"%Y%m%d"` and similar, but still I am getting `Error: 1`.

In shell emulator I get `bad date '+1 day'`

Cannot find any android shell commands reference or man.

Some guides recommend using %TIMES variable, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, I had to learn to use Tasker a bit, the solution is a little awkward but it probably should be done this way in Tasker.

The most important variable for such datetime manipulations in Tasker is a global variable `%TIMES` which contains current time in seconds - so it is a big long integer number.

Adding e.g. 30 days to it means you need to *Set variable* (with Math on) like this:

```
%TIMES + (30 * 86400)
```

Tommorow is:

```
%TIMES + (1 * 86400)
```

The main problem is, that you have to convert the value to a formatted datetime string. As I understood it there is no built in command for that in Tasker.

You need to create JavaScriptlet task step for that and paste there [the code from this page](http://tasker.wikidot.com/getformatteddate):

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.1b1m">
    <Task sr="task54">
        <cdate>1340586441681</cdate>
        <edate>1369445351826</edate>
        <id>54</id>
        <nme>getFormattedDate</nme>
        <pri>10</pri>
        <rty>2</rty>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="3">
            <code>129</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">var gsMonthNames = new Array(
'January',
'February',
'March',
'April',
'May',
'June',
'July',
'August',
'September',
'October',
'November',
'December'
);

var gsDayNames = new Array(
'Sunday',
'Monday',
'Tuesday',
'Wednesday',
'Thursday',
'Friday',
'Saturday'
);

var d = new Date(par[0] * 1000);
var f = par[1];

var formatteddate = f.replace(/(yyyy|yy|mmmm|mmm|mm|dddd|ddd|dd|hh|nn|ss|a\/p)/gi,
    function($1)
    {
        switch ($1)
        {
        case 'yyyy': return d.getFullYear();
        case 'yy':   return ('0' + d.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
        case 'mmmm': return gsMonthNames[d.getMonth()];
        case 'mmm':  return gsMonthNames[d.getMonth()].slice(0,3);
        case 'mm':   return ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        case 'dddd': return gsDayNames[d.getDay()];
        case 'ddd':  return gsDayNames[d.getDay()].slice(0,3);
        case 'dd':   return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
        case 'hh':   return ('0' + ((h = d.getHours() % 12) ? h : 12)).slice(-2);
        case 'HH':   return ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2);
        case 'nn':   return ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        case 'ss':   return ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
        case 'a/p':  return d.getHours() &lt; 12 ? 'a' : 'p';
        }
    }
);</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">45</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="45"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="3">
            <code>126</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%formatteddate</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

before that Javascriptlet step you insert 2 steps where you set two input variables `%par1` (contains datetime in seconds form previous step) and `%par2` (contains `yyyymmdd` - date format).

The formatted date string is available then in `%formatteddate` variable.

---

As for getting the next week:

- Run Shell `date -d +"%Y"` to  `%year`
- Run Shell  `date -d +"%V"` to `%week`
- Set variable `%week` to `%week + 1` (Do Maths On)
- Set variable `%year` to `%year + 1` (Do Maths On) (If `%week > 52`)
- Set variable `%week` to `1` (If `%week > 52`)
- The `yyyyww.htm` of the next week can then be written as `%year%week.htm`

Comment: 52*7 = 364; a normal year has 365 days and a leap year has 366 days. Beacuse of this discrepancy, regardless of whether week 1 is taken to be the first full week or the first week with 4 days or more in the new year, occasionally there will be a week 53.

Answer (score 1):

Given a variable `%mytimestamp` set to an epoch timestamp you can use this in your shell action:

`date -d @%mytimestamp +%Y%m%d`

Note the `@` before `%mytimestamp`

---

```
$ adb shell
$ date --version
toybox 0.7.4-android
$ date --help
usage: date [-u] [-r FILE] [-d DATE] [+DISPLAY_FORMAT] [-D SET_FORMAT] [SET]


Set/get the current date/time. With no SET shows the current date.

Default SET format is "MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]", that's (2 digits each)
month, day, hour (0-23), and minute. Optionally century, year, and second.
Also accepts "@UNIXTIME[.FRACTION]" as seconds since midnight Jan 1 1970.

-d      Show DATE instead of current time (convert date format)
-D      +FORMAT for SET or -d (instead of MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss])
-r      Use modification time of FILE instead of current date
-u      Use UTC instead of current timezone

+FORMAT specifies display format string using strftime(3) syntax:

%% literal %             %n newline              %t tab
%S seconds (00-60)       %M minute (00-59)       %m month (01-12)
%H hour (0-23)           %I hour (01-12)         %p AM/PM
%y short year (00-99)    %Y year                 %C century
%a short weekday name    %A weekday name         %u day of week (1-7, 1=mon)
%b short month name      %B month name           %Z timezone name
%j day of year (001-366) %d day of month (01-31) %e day of month ( 1-31)
%N nanosec (output only)

%U Week of year (0-53 start sunday)   %W Week of year (0-53 start monday)
%V Week of year (1-53 start monday, week < 4 days not part of this year)

%D = "%m/%d/%y"    %r = "%I : %M : %S %p"   %T = "%H:%M:%S"   %h = "%b"
%x locale date     %X locale time           %c locale date/time
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

tomorrow=$(( `date +%s` + 86400 ))

date -d @$tomorrow +%Y%m%d

[image]